# How to access netgear router web interface

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

What I am trying to do is access the traffic meter data on my local netgear router.  It's easy enough to login to it and click on the link, but ideally I would like a little app that sits down in the system tray (windows) that I can check whenever I want to see what my network traffic is.

I'm using python to try to access the router's web page, but I've run into some snags.  I originally tried modified a script that would reboot the router (found here https://github.com/ncw/router-rebooter/blob/master/router_rebooter.py) but it just serves up the raw html and I need it after the onload javascript functions have run.  This type of thing is described in many posts about web scraping and people suggested using selenium.

I tried selenium and have run into two problems.  First, it actually opens the browser window, which is not what I want.  Second, it skips the stuff I put in to pass the HTTP authentication and pops up the login window anyway.  Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

baseAddress = '192.168.1.1'
baseURL = 'http://%(user)s:%(pwd)s@%(host)s/traffic_meter.htm'

username = 'admin'
pwd = 'thisisnotmyrealpassword'

url = baseURL % {
  'user': username,
  'pwd': pwd,
  'host': baseAddress
  }

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('network.http.phishy-userpass-length', 255)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get(url)
```

So, my question is, what is the best way to accomplish what I want without having it launch a visible web browser window?

**Update:**
Okay, I tried sircapsalot's suggestion and modified the script to this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from contextlib import closing

url = 'http://admin:notmyrealpassword@192.168.1.1/start.htm'

with closing(webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNIT)) as driver:
  driver.get(url)
  print(driver.page_source)
```

This fixes the web browser being loaded, but it failed the authentication.  Any suggestions?

Comment: if you didn't want it to be visible, then you can try a Headless Browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution and it was way easier than I thought.  I did try John1024's suggestion and was able to download the proper webpage from the router using wget.  However I didn't like the fact that wget saved the result to a file, which I would then have to open and parse.

I ended up going back to the original reboot_router.py script I had attempted to modify unsuccessfully the first time.  My problem was I was trying to make it too complicated.  This is the final script I ended up using:

```
import urllib2

user = 'admin'
pwd = 'notmyrealpassword'
host = '192.168.1.1'
url = 'http://' + host + '/traffic_meter_2nd.htm'

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, host, user, pwd)
authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)

opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)
response = opener.open(url)
stuff = response.read()
response.close()

print stuff
```

This prints out the entire traffic meter webpage from my router, with its proper values loaded.  I can then take this and parse the values out of it.  The nice thing about this is it has no external dependencies like selenium, wget or other libraries that needs to be installed.  Clean is good.

Thank you, everyone, for your suggestions.  I wouldn't have gotten to this answer without them.

Comment: Glad it worked.  For future reference, `wget` doesn't have to save to a file.  `wget -nv -O - http://router/...` sends the output to `stdout` which a script can then parse directly.  That is what I use.

Comment: @John1024 Thanks, that will probably come in handy later.

Comment: You guys saved me from using selenium. :)

Answer (score 2):

The web interface for my Netgear router (WNDR3700) is also filled with javascript.  Yours may differ but I have found that my scripts can get all the info they need without javascript.

The first step is finding the correct URL.  Using FireFox, I went to the traffic page and then used "This Frame -> Show only this frame" to discover that the URL for the traffic page on my router is:

```
http://my_router_address/traffic.htm
```

After finding this URL, no web browswer and no javascript is needed.  I can, for example, capture this page with `wget`:

```
wget http://my_router_address/traffic.htm
```

Using a text editor on the resulting traffic.htm file, I see that the traffic data is available in a lengthy block that starts:

```
var traffic_today_time="1486:37";
var traffic_today_up="1,959";
var traffic_today_down="1,945";
var traffic_today_total="3,904";
. . . .
```

Thus, the `traffic.htm` file can be easily captured and parsed with the scripting language of your choice.  No javascript ever needs to be executed.

UPDATE: I have a `~/.netrc` file with a line in it like:

```
machine my_router_address login someloginname password somepassword
```

Before `wget` downloads from the router, it retrieves the login info from this file.  This has security advantages.  If one runs `wget http://name@password...`, then the password is viewable to all on your machine via the process list (`ps a`).  Using `.netrc`, this never happens.  Restrictive permissions can be set on `.netrc`, e.g. readable only by user (`chmod 400 ~/.netrc`).

Comment: How did you handle the authentication/login with wget?

Comment: On other routers, I have used the http://user@password... approach.  On my Netgear, however, `wget` can download information pages without authentication.

Comment: @Murrgon CORRECTION:  I keep the name/password info in a `~/.netrc` file.